# Java recursive ABC generator with prefix

Tags: java, recursion

I have a recursive ABC generator method.

```
public static void ABCgenerator(String from, int letters) {
        if (from.length() == letters) {
            System.out.println(from);
        } else {
            ABCgenerator(from + "a", letters);
            ABCgenerator(from + "b", letters);
            ABCgenerator(from + "c", letters);
        }
    }
```

When I run it with these parameters `ABCgenerator("a", 3);` It gives me:

```
aaa
aab
aac
aba
abb
abc
aca
acb
acc
```

Instead I'd like to get the following when running `ABCgenerator("a", 3);`:

```
aaaa
aaab
aaac
aaba
aabb
aabc
aaca
aacb
aacc
abaa
abab
abac
abba
abbb
abbc
abca
abcb
abcc
acaa
acab
acac
acba
acbb
acbc
acca
accb
accc
```

The catch is that **I'm only allowed to change the method's body**.

The type and the number of the input parameters have to be unchanged, 1 String + 1 int.

**The method has to be remain recursive.**

How can I do that?

**Edit:**

With `ABCgenerator("", 3);`

It has to give:

```
aaa
aab
aac
aba
abb
abc
aca
acb
acc
baa
bab
bac
bba
bbb
bbc
bca
bcb
bcc
caa
cab
cac
cba
cbb
cbc
cca
ccb
ccc
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public static void ABCgenerator(String from, int lettersLeft) {
        lettersLeft--;
        if (lettersLeft + 1 == 0) {
            System.out.println(from);
        } else {
            ABCgenerator(from + "a", lettersLeft);
            ABCgenerator(from + "b", lettersLeft);
            ABCgenerator(from + "c", lettersLeft);
        }
    }
}
```

This is the right solution. Instead of calculating the whole length of the input string each time, we're just counting how many letters the function still has to generate, when it reaches zero the "last" instance wont call other instances just prints the result. I wanted something that generates all the combinations of the letters a b c with a given length and with a fixed prefix and this does just like that. It gives the desired output(s) provided in the example.

Comment: Don't just drop some code without any explanations please.

Comment: There it is. Any questions?